# Dynamically Inserting short code into WooCommerce product description pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[Woo_stamped_io type="widget"]'); ?>
```

The php code above is located in our products_single.php and puts the wiget at the bottom of the product page.

However I would like to place this under the description but above other content (like related products for example)

I thought i might be able to do it with jquery and tried

```
<script> $([Woo_stamped_io type="widget"]).insertAfter( $("#tab-description"));</script>
```

I also tried

`<script> $("[Woo_stamped_io type="widget"]").insertAfter( $("#tab-description"));</script>`

but i know u cant actually do this in jquery now. How is it done in PHP?

I can insert the shortcode manually into each description field but we have thousands of products so its not an ideal solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add this to description of all products' description, then you can directly query on mysql like this.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = concat(post_content , '[Woo_stamped_io type="widget"]') WHERE post_type = 'product';
```

I hope this helps!

---

You can customize this woocommerce template: woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\description.php Add the short code here.

Comment: thanks! Do i need to manually add it to new products after that or do I perform the msql command every time i add products?

Thanks!

Comment: For new products, you will have to take care manually in future. Make sure in future, while adding new products, you don't run the same query again. Otherwise the older products will get the shortcode assigned twice.

may be you can put some check based on date for future query.

Comment: Thanks! Ill consider this as an option for sure. Theres no easy way to just insert shortcode into every description via the functions.php file?

Comment: There is a way other than this! You can customize this woocommerce template: woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs\description.php 

Add the short code here.

Comment: Yeah i considered that but than our code will be removed on every woocommerce update. That is what i was told.

Comment: Woocommerce template are meant so that we can override it and they don't get overwritten with an update. you can copy the template to your theme file and then customize it.

Here is a link on how to customize woocommerce template: http://websitetutorials.grafix.gr/e-shop/woocommerce/override-woocommerce-template-files/

Comment: THIS is what i needed to learn. THANKS SO MUCH! Please add it to your answer.

Comment: Added it to my answer. You can accept this one as answer now!